# .env variables not being accessed in deployment in GitHub pages (Vite + react app)

Tags: github, vite, github-pages, .env

Repo:https://github.com/SyntaxWarrior30/Java-Docs-Generator

I deployed the site as a gh-pages of the main branch using the dist folder.

The GitHub pages site doesn’t work since the API key, stored in the .env file, which was ignored with .gitignore, is not being accessed. I created a secret variable in my GitHub pages environment yet it is still not working. How do I add .env variables to my GitHub pages so my fetch function works properly.

What my .env.production file looks like:

```
VITE_API_KEY={My API Key}
```

I tried adding a new repository secret by navigating to Settings > Secrets > New repository secret. Naming the secret the same as the variable name I defined in .env, without the `VITE_` prefix. However, this did not fix the problem.

I also tried the solution where I include the `VITE_` prefix for the Secret variable name in Github.

Here is the static.yml that i used to deploy the project, if needed:

```
    # Simple workflow for deploying static content to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ['main']

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets the GITHUB_TOKEN permissions to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: 'pages'
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Single deploy job since we're just deploying
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          # Upload dist repository
          path: './dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

Evidence of error:

[image]

Comment: Github Secrets and .env both present values to your app as [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). If your app is looking for VITE_API_KEY then use VITE_API_KEY in both Github Secrets and .env.

Comment: @Schwern I tried that but it still dosen't work, any other ideas? Right now, my Secret variable name is VITE_API_KEY, along with its corresponding api key.

Comment: @Schwern I have updated the question with new information, if needed.

Comment: How did you build it?

Comment: Note that ["subtree" has a special meaning in Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree). Did you mean the "gh-pages" branch?

Comment: yes, i used gh-pages

Comment: You're passing the env to the checkout step which doesn't use it. Pass it to the build step.

Comment: @Schwern I updated the .yml file, it still doesn’t work. I don't know what seems to be the problem. Should I try to host the site on a diffrent platform but keep the source code in github?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with GitHub for this. Your build step no longer does anything, the build command is missing. Your build step needs to run the build command with the env set, like in my answer. I would recommend getting it working on the command line before trying to implement it in an action.

Comment: @Schwern Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by getting it working in command line. My program is working when I run "npm run build" & "npm run preview" in VS code.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work by updating the static.yml. I updated the question's .yml file to what worked for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GiridharNair I'm glad you got it working. For the future, don't update the question with what worked. Then the discussion and answers don't make any sense. Instead, if you're not satisfied with the existing answers, self-answer like you did.

Comment: @Schwern I realized my mistake in putting the answer in the question itself, i reverted it back to the original post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the program to work, below is my .yml file for reference:

```
# Simple workflow for deploying static content to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ['main']

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets the GITHUB_TOKEN permissions to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: 'pages'
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Single deploy job since we're just deploying
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          VITE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.VITE_API_KEY }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          # Upload dist repository
          path: './dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Vite needs to be built and deployed with `vite build` (or your package manager's equivalent). During `vite build`, the values are injected into the new code. They'd have to be since this is client code run on the browser. They can come from either `.env`, or a special `.env.production`, or environment variables. See [.env files in the Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) and [Deploying For Production](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html).

Make sure this is done before deploying to Github.

---

If you want to build and deploy with Github actions, see [vite-deploy-demo](https://github.com/sitek94/vite-deploy-demo) and the [Vite docs for Github Pages](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages).

Your VITE values must be [available as environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets) during the `vite build` step.

1. Add your production VITE values as Github Secrets.
2. Make them available to the build step.

```
      - name: Build project
        run: vite build
        env:
          VITE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.VITE_API_KEY }}
```

Comment: When you mean by the build step, you mean when I create a .yml file for deployment in workflows?

Comment: @GiridharNair I mean `vite build`. Doesn't matter if it's in a Github Action or manually on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, after days of looking for a way to solve this, it seems that the only way to set an environment variable from secrets is to do it during the step where the project is built.

```yaml
- name: Build project
    run: npm run build
    env:
      REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
```

A complete action for deploying a react app from GitHub pages with secrets is

```yaml
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false
jobs:
  build:
    environment:
        name: github-pages
        url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "21"
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build
        env:
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: ./build
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v3
```